# What import declaration do I need for cvGetMinMaxHistValues?

Tags: function, opencv, reference, import, javacv

I am trying to use the cvGetMinMaxHistValues to find said values, with Javacv, when I use the function it says that the function is not declared in my class. I have already imported:

```
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.*;
```

what import do I need for this function?

Also, is there a reference that I can use to find which libs I need to import for each opencv function. It is very annoying to have to go hunting on google for each function that I want to use.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you mean `cvGetMinMaxHistValue`, and not `cvGetMinMaxHistValues`?

( which in fact exists in imgproc )

Answer (score 0):

For the `cvGetMinMaxHistValues` it is:

```
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.cvGetMinMaxHistValue;
```

Here is a list of imports that can be helpful for you:

```
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvCreateImage;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.cvLoadImage;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.CV_BGR2GRAY;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.cvCalcHist;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.cvCvtColor;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.CV_RGB;
import com.googlecode.javacv.CanvasFrame;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.*;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.CvHistogram;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.CV_HIST_ARRAY;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_legacy.cvQueryHistValue_1D;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.CV_FILLED;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvPoint;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvRectangle;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.cvCreateHist;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImageArray;
```